# Python while loop logic

Tags: python, while-loop

When I run my program on Python Shell. It runs fine for T,D,A,H,L but when I enter E after I enter T,D,A,H,L the end1() function runs and the totals() function runs again right after as well. If I restart the program and only enter E the program runs just fine.

```
dayArray = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]; #This is the array for the days.
    consumedArray = [2600,2400,3500,3200,2700,3300,3000]; #This is the array for the calories consumed.
    burnedArray = [150,100,200,180,250,100,50]; #This is the array for the calories burned.



def main(): #This is the main module.
    calories = 0 #This is the variable for the calories.
    day = "" #This is the variable for the day.
    letter = "" #This is the variable for the letter.
    totals = 0 #This is the variable for the totals.
    difference = 0 #This is the variable for the differences.
    average = 0.0 #This is the variable for the average.
    max1 = 0 #This is the variable for the max.
    min1 = 0 #This is the variable for the min.
    flag = False #This is the variable for the flag.
    counter = 1 #This is the variable for the counter.
    index = 1 #This is the variable for the index.
    intro() 
    decisions()


def intro(): #This is the intro module.
    print("Welcome to the program!! Enjoy!!") #This is the message to welcome you to the program.
    print("*"*60) #Prints 60 stars.

def decisions(): #This is the decisions module.
    print("What do you want to do? ") #This is asking you what you want to do.
    print("T = Get Totals") #This is if you type in "T" you will get totals.
    print("D = Find Differences") #This is if you type in "D" you will find differences.
    print("A = Find Averages") #This is if you type in "A" you will find the averages.
    print("H = Find Highest") #This is if you type in "H" you will find the highest.
    print("L = Find Lowest") #This is if you type in "L" you will find the lowest.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    letter = str(input("What do you want to do? ")) #This is asking you what you want to do.
    print("You entered: ", letter) #This is telling you what letter you have entered.
    flag=False;
    while flag != True:    #This is the loop for letter doesnt equals E
        if letter == "T":   #This is if letter is equal to T.
            print("like anything")
            totals()
            print("like anything")
        elif letter == "D": #This is if letter is equal to D.
            differences()
        elif letter == "A": #This is if letter is equal to A.
            averages()
        elif letter == "H": #This is if letter is equal to H.
            max1()
        elif letter == "L": #This is if letter is equal to L.
            min1()
        elif letter == "E":
            break



        else:
            print("restart and try again")    #Anything else end program
            break
                       #when while loop ends end the program
    end1()



def differences(): #This is the differences module.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print('Day          Calories Consumed          Calories Burned'); #This is the output for the column names.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    for i in range(7): #This is saying i is in the range of 7.
        x = consumedArray[i] - burnedArray[i]; #This is the formula for the differences.
        print("{0:10s} {1:12d}" .format(dayArray[i],x)) #This is the output for the days and the differences.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    decisions() #run decisions to restart the main content of the program

def totals(): #This is the totals module.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print('Day          Calories Consumed          Calories Burned'); #This is the output for the column names.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    for i in range(7): #This is saying i is in the range of 7.
        print("{0:10s} {1:12d} {2:25d}" .format(dayArray[i], consumedArray[i], burnedArray[i])) #This is the output for the totals of days, consumed, and burned.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    decisions() #run decisions to restart the main content of the program    

def averages(): #This is the averages module.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    average1 = sum(consumedArray) / len(consumedArray); #This is the formula for the Average Calories Consumed.
    average2 = sum(burnedArray) / len(burnedArray); #This is the formula for th Average Calories Burned.
    print("Average Calories Consumed %.2f"% average1) #This is the output for the Average Calories Consumed at 2 decimal places as a float.
    print("Average Calories Burned %.2f"% average2) #This is the output for the Average Calories Burned at 2 decimal places as a float.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    decisions() #run decisions to restart the main content of the program

def max1(): #This the max1 module.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    maxconsumed = max(consumedArray); #This is finding the highest amount of calories consumed.
    maxburned = max(burnedArray); #This is finding the highest amount of calories burned.
    i = consumedArray.index(maxconsumed); #This is setting the highest amount of calories consumed in the index.
    j = burnedArray.index(maxburned); #This is setting the highest amount of calories burned in the index.
    print("Highest Calories Consumed {0:10s} {1:2d}" .format(dayArray[i],maxconsumed)) #This is the output for the highest calories consumed.
    print("Highest Calories Burned {0:10s} {1:2d}" .format(dayArray[i],maxburned)) #This is the output for the highest calories burned.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    decisions() #run decisions to restart the main content of the program

def min1(): #This is the min1 module.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    minconsumed = min(consumedArray); #This is finding the lowest amount of calories consumed.
    minburned = min(burnedArray); #This is finding the lowest amount of calories burned.
    i = consumedArray.index(minconsumed); #This is setting the lowest amount of calories consumed in the index.
    j = burnedArray.index(minburned); #This is setting the lowest amount of calories burned in the index.
    print("Lowest Calories Consumed {0:10s} {1:2d}" .format(dayArray[i],minconsumed)) #This is the output for the lowest calories consumed.
    print("Lowest Calories Burned {0:10s} {1:2d}" .format(dayArray[i],minburned)) #This is the output for the lowest calories burned.
    print('*'*60); #Prints 60 stars.
    print();
    decisions() #run decisions to restart the main content of the program

def end1(): #This is the end module.
    print("You have finished the program!!"); #This is telling you that you have finished the program.


main() #This is telling the program to run all of the modules.
```

Comment: Side note: that is a ridiculous case of over-commenting.

Comment: @StevenCumming Your professor seems to be a little OCD in that case with comments. Or did you misunderstand and go a bit overhard?

Comment: @StevenCumming your professor seems to not understand what variable naming is for.

Comment: I got half off last time for too little comments so I'm being a smart ass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you have both an infinite loop and improper recursion.

**The improper recursion:**

The other letters start up another `decisions` function call, which has its own loop.

In other words, `decisions()` (instance 1) --> `totals()` after letter "T" --> `decisions()` (instance 2) --> etc....

When the letter 'E' is entered, only the latest `decisions` loop ends. The previous loops continue (in this case infinitely).

**The infinite loop:**

Also, since you are asking for the letter before you enter the while loop, any letter that does not end the while loop will cause an infinite loop. For example, entering "T" will constantly repeat the following:

```
while flag != True:  # flag is never True, by the way
    if letter == "T":   # this is always True
        ...   # this will be parsed over and over again since it does not break
```

**To fix the program**, get rid of all instances of `decisions()` except for the main call and move the `letter = str(input(...` line into the while loop.

This version works, for example:

```
dayArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
            "Sunday"]  # This is the array for the days.
consumedArray = [2600, 2400, 3500, 3200, 2700, 3300,
                 3000]  # This is the array for the calories consumed.
burnedArray = [150, 100, 200, 180, 250, 100,
               50]  # This is the array for the calories burned.


def main():  # This is the main module.
    calories = 0  #This is the variable for the calories.
    day = ""  #This is the variable for the day.
    letter = ""  #This is the variable for the letter.
    totals = 0  #This is the variable for the totals.
    difference = 0  #This is the variable for the differences.
    average = 0.0  #This is the variable for the average.
    max1 = 0  #This is the variable for the max.
    min1 = 0  #This is the variable for the min.
    flag = False  #This is the variable for the flag.
    counter = 1  #This is the variable for the counter.
    index = 1  #This is the variable for the index.
    intro()
    decisions()


def intro():  # This is the intro module.
    print(
        "Welcome to the program!! Enjoy!!")  #This is the message to welcome you to the program.
    print("*" * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.


def decisions():  # This is the decisions module.
    print("What do you want to do? ")  #This is asking you what you want to do.
    print("T = Get Totals")  #This is if you type in "T" you will get totals.
    print("D = Find Differences")  #This is if you type in "D" you will find differences.
    print("A = Find Averages")  #This is if you type in "A" you will find the averages.
    print("H = Find Highest")  #This is if you type in "H" you will find the highest.
    print("L = Find Lowest")  #This is if you type in "L" you will find the lowest.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    flag = False
    while flag != True:  #This is the loop for letter doesnt equals E
        letter = str(input("What do you want to do? "))  #This is asking you what you want to do.
        print("You entered: ", letter)  #This is telling you what letter you have entered.
        if letter == "T":  #This is if letter is equal to T.
            print("like anything")
            totals()
            print("like anything")
        elif letter == "D":  #This is if letter is equal to D.
            differences()
        elif letter == "A":  #This is if letter is equal to A.
            averages()
        elif letter == "H":  #This is if letter is equal to H.
            max1()
        elif letter == "L":  #This is if letter is equal to L.
            min1()
        elif letter == "E":
            break



        else:
            print("restart and try again")  #Anything else end program
            break
            #when while loop ends end the program
    end1()


def differences():  # This is the differences module.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print(
        'Day          Calories Consumed          Calories Burned')  #This is the output for the column names.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    for i in range(7):  #This is saying i is in the range of 7.
        x = consumedArray[i] - burnedArray[i]  #This is the formula for the differences.
        print("{0:10s} {1:12d}".format(dayArray[i],
                                       x))  #This is the output for the days and the differences.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    # decisions()  #run decisions to restart the main content of the program


def totals():  # This is the totals module.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print(
        'Day          Calories Consumed          Calories Burned')  #This is the output for the column names.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    for i in range(7):  #This is saying i is in the range of 7.
        print("{0:10s} {1:12d} {2:25d}".format(dayArray[i], consumedArray[i], burnedArray[
            i]))  #This is the output for the totals of days, consumed, and burned.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    # decisions()  #run decisions to restart the main content of the program


def averages():  # This is the averages module.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    average1 = sum(consumedArray) / len(
        consumedArray)  #This is the formula for the Average Calories Consumed.
    average2 = sum(burnedArray) / len(
        burnedArray)  #This is the formula for th Average Calories Burned.
    print(
        "Average Calories Consumed %.2f" % average1)  #This is the output for the Average Calories Consumed at 2 decimal places as a float.
    print(
        "Average Calories Burned %.2f" % average2)  #This is the output for the Average Calories Burned at 2 decimal places as a float.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    # decisions()  #run decisions to restart the main content of the program


def max1():  # This the max1 module.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    maxconsumed = max(
        consumedArray)  #This is finding the highest amount of calories consumed.
    maxburned = max(burnedArray)  #This is finding the highest amount of calories burned.
    i = consumedArray.index(
        maxconsumed)  #This is setting the highest amount of calories consumed in the index.
    j = burnedArray.index(
        maxburned)  #This is setting the highest amount of calories burned in the index.
    print("Highest Calories Consumed {0:10s} {1:2d}".format(dayArray[i],
                                                            maxconsumed))  #This is the output for the highest calories consumed.
    print("Highest Calories Burned {0:10s} {1:2d}".format(dayArray[i],
                                                          maxburned))  #This is the output for the highest calories burned.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    # decisions()  #run decisions to restart the main content of the program


def min1():  # This is the min1 module.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    minconsumed = min(
        consumedArray)  #This is finding the lowest amount of calories consumed.
    minburned = min(burnedArray)  #This is finding the lowest amount of calories burned.
    i = consumedArray.index(
        minconsumed)  #This is setting the lowest amount of calories consumed in the index.
    j = burnedArray.index(
        minburned)  #This is setting the lowest amount of calories burned in the index.
    print("Lowest Calories Consumed {0:10s} {1:2d}".format(dayArray[i],
                                                           minconsumed))  #This is the output for the lowest calories consumed.
    print("Lowest Calories Burned {0:10s} {1:2d}".format(dayArray[i],
                                                         minburned))  #This is the output for the lowest calories burned.
    print('*' * 60)  #Prints 60 stars.
    print()
    # decisions()  #run decisions to restart the main content of the program


def end1():  # This is the end module.
    print(
        "You have finished the program!!")  #This is telling you that you have finished the program.


main()  #This is telling the program to run all of the modules.
```

Comment: Also, the variable `flag` isn't doing anything. Just use `while True`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because all of your functions end by running function decisions again. So you start with main, you then run decisions, then say you choose option T to run function totals. Because function totals ends with decisions() you now have two loops of decisions running. So when you press E to break the loop you only break the most recent decisions loop and it drops you back into the previous one. Get rid of all those decisions() at the end of all your functions and it will start working better. You don't need to tell the program to go back to descisions. When you finish the function that you called in decisions it will automatically drop back into the loop. As a side note, more comments are better then less but I agree with the previous poster, this is a little bit overkill with the comments.